# How can I move the second line up vertically, reducing the space between it and the line above it?

Tags: html, css

I've tried reducing the vertical space between two lines of text using various CSS properties, such as `margin-top` and `padding`, but nothing seems to work.

The two lines look like so:

[image]

I want them much closer together, so that they are almost touching. No matter what I do with the `margin-top` property, though, it's not enough and eventually gets to a point where I'm making things even worse.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

```
<style>
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.titletext {
    font-size: 2.8em;
    color: darkgreen;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    margin-left: -32px;
}
.titletextjr {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: darkgreen;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
    margin-left: -32px;   
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container body-content">
<div class="jumbotronjr">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 1cm">
        <img src="http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png" alt="PRO*ACT usa logo">
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <label class="titletext" style="margin-top: 0.1cm;">eServices Reporting</label>
    <br/>
        <label class="titletextjr" style="margin-top: -2cm;">Purchasing Report for RB Kitchen</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What change or addition do I need to make to get these lines closer together (specifically, for the second line to move up vertically)?

Comment: If you want them almost touching then why do you have a line break in-between them?

Comment: So they won't be on the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a large space between them because your `.jumbotronjr` class has a `line-height: 2.1428571435;`. Remove this and it will remove the space between your text.

```
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435; /* <--- Remove this */
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jt7qjLk4/)

Comment: Or modify it to whatever height you see fit.

Comment: Yeah or do that ^ Haha.

Answer (score 2):

The limited-flexibility with vertical space is due to the `<br>` tag. The alternative approach would be to remove the `<br>` and display the `labels` as blocks in order to get the stacked appearance. Then, as you can see, your spacing margins and paddings (even line-heights) work as intended.

```css
.jumbotronjr {
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2.1428571435;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
.titletext {
  font-size: 2.8em;
  color: darkgreen;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
  margin-left: -32px;
  display:block;
}
.titletextjr {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: darkgreen;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Cambria, serif;
  margin-left: -32px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-content">
  <div class="jumbotronjr">
    <label class="titletext" style="margin-top: 0.1cm;">eServices Reporting</label>
    <label class="titletextjr" style="margin-top: -2cm;">Purchasing Report for RB Kitchen</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you play with `line-height` instead of using margins etc? This is a quite big value:

```
line-height: 2.1428571435;
```

Put sth smaller in there according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any control over the markup? The use of the `<label>` tag here is incorrect. From Mozilla Developer Network - "*The HTML Label Element () represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the  element, or by using the for attribute.*" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

For proper semantics, I would recommend changing these to header tags as they seem to convey a heading on the page.

By simply changing these elements and removing the `<br>` tag I believe you will achieve the desired effect:

```
    <h1 class="titletext" style="margin-top: 0.1cm;">eServices Reporting</h1>
    <h2 class="titletextjr" style="margin-top: -2cm;">Purchasing Report for RB Kitchen</h2>
```

If you insist on using the `<label>` tags, you could adjust the line height to a value of "1".